# In 2014 has any SEO value rewriting urls?

Tags: seo, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In 2014 has any SEO value rewriting urls?

If my site consistently links product page, and that product page shows a consistent canonical url, is there a real SEO doing this

```
http://example.com/products/woman-tracksuit-in-hemp
```

instead of this

```
http://example.com/product.php?id=6588
```

I know that a human being would be more comfortable with a rewrited url, but I would like to focus on SEO and bots, especially Google

Answer (score 1):

Yes, search engines still uses keywords from the friendly URL as a ranking factor on search queries.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the search engine.  There is some value in Google, but not a ton.  We have found exact match domains to be much more successful in Bing.  We have a number of exact match domains that don't rank at all in Google that are usually in the top 10 in Bing, although Bing is very volatile, so that could change at any time.

Comment: in Italy (my country) Google is the master, unfortunately other search engines are nearly irrelevant

Comment: That is true to a certain extent everywhere, I think Google has 60 or 70% of the search market here, but there is still some traffic to be had through Bing and Yahoo especially